# Cross Platform Compilation of C++ .exe

Tags: c++11, multi-platform

I have been asked to re-write an old C/C++ project in C++11. The old project is multi-platform, however, in order to deploy the system on other architectures the current process is to log into a remote service which has all the available target platforms (Red Hat Linux, Umbuntu, Sco Unix et al.) and build the .exe on each platform for distribution.

Is there a way that I can send the user a package that will self-compile on their architecture and build the correct .exe *without giving the source code*?

I am also open to cross-compilation to get around having to log into separate servers and compile for each platform. How easy or not is it to compile a code for different architectures using a cross compiler?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't build binaries for everything yourself and distribute those?  VMs make it a lot easier and cheaper than it used to be.

Comment: I am already building the binaries for each platform and distributing those - this takes time and money to do. What I want to know is any fancy method in which I can supply some sort of Bootstrapper to the user which will compile/build the .exe for them. Perhaps using object files instead of source files?

Comment: You might automate the process of doing the remote build.  You can `ssh < filename` to inject compile commands from a file into an ssh session.  That can provide a 'one click' solution on your end to build all the necessary executables.

Comment: This is known as [build farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_farm) and is unavoidable.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot compile source code without source code.

But you can probably compile or even cross-compile the code locally and send the different compiled files

```
my_exe_rhel8
my_exe_ubuntu_x64
```

and the user can then start the correct one.

Ideally, you would package the binaries for those systems already, so for ubuntu, you would prepare a .deb, for red hat, an rpm. That way you can make it much easier for your clients to make sure they get the right versions, have dependencies installed and so on...

As Btrfl noted, you can use VMs to easily create a setup where you can locally compile all binaries on their respective platforms.

Comment: But this is what I have said we are doing now. We compile all of the versions and send the correct one upon request. What I want is a method whereby we can send out a generic package which they can compile on there own architecture without us having to compile for all platforms...

Comment: You cannot compile source code without source code.

Comment: Dude, I understand that. There are things like cross-compilers and other tools that I am not familiar with that could potentially help me here. Moreover, there may be something that I can do with object files and some sort of Bootstrapper/MakeFile. I would like to hear suggestions of possible solutions, not just 'No'.

Comment: A cross compiler transforms source code (input) into a binary (output) that is (cross) for a different platform than the one you are compiling on. The input is still source code.

Comment: Agreed, the issue I need to get around is the requirement to log on to expensive servers to compile for each platform and there are many. The time on these servers is like 1000USD per hour and it takes a while to do this. Any other way apart from going on to the correct architecture and 'manually' compiling I am open to...

Comment: That's a different question, but luckily, [Blrfl](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/20756/blrfl) already answered it in a comment: Use VMs (virtual machines).

Comment: There has to be a better way than that, surely?

Comment: You seem to think it's a bad way. It's not. VMs are great. I don't understand why you would not happily use VMs instead of various servers under outside control...In many ways, it's even better than cross compilation because you can use the built-in package management for dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps VMs are the way to go then...

Comment: if you have the correct dependencies, can you not compile using the same compiler (eg gcc) and simply specify a different set of compiler flags? I know gcc is used to cross-compile some Windows libs from a Linux box (eg ffmpeg)

Comment: @gbjbaanb Sure, but it's usually easier to (as an example) use ```apt-get install mydependency-dev``` on ubuntu and not worry about it instead of properly setting up your library dependency for whatever platform on another platform.

Comment: @Wilbert do it the easy way, or the correct way. Or to put it another way - do it the simple way that works now, or the correct way that will work when the versions change sometime in the future....  I know, I know, easy always wins :)

Comment: @gbjbaanb If you use the dependency provided by the os, you are safer. Otherwise you have to locally keep your library build settings synchronized with whatever all of your target platform maintainers are doing.

Comment: @Wilbert yes, but that's not quite the point - you have to keep your packages updated to what your customers use. So if you have one on latest Ubuntu and another on LTS, you have 2 machines to manage. Hence the "correct" way is to sort out a build with all the combinations you use. If you only have 1 or 2, its easier to have a VM. If you end up with tens... things get quite different, especially if you don't upgrade your program until its been fully tested against the latest upgrades. YMMV.

Comment: *"The time on these servers is like 1000USD per hour..."* This sounds extremely wrong, and may have shaped OP's unconscionable opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could compile the source to bytecode using LLVM and then produce binaries using that but... its a lot of unknown hassle for something that is easily fixed by changing your position so slightly.

Comment: That doesn't actually work; LLVM bitcode isn't platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

If the executables are not too large, could you package them all together and then distribute an installer that chooses and installs the correct executable? The customer would end up getting a version of the compiled code for each platform, but if you just zip them up into a single file they'd never know the difference. Of course, this might not work if you have space constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The only other thing I think you could do is to compile the source to object files, send them the object files, and then have them link the code on their end.  But that just creates more issues than it's worth.

If their compiler can see the source code, they can see the source code.  You could, as some suggested, go from source down to some intermediate representation used by the compiler, but that varies compiler to compiler.

Okay, I see, you're talking about renting machine time for each build.  Cross compilers might help, but I've only seen that done well for the same O/S but on a different architecture (cross compiling a Linux program for PPC on an x86).

Otherwise, in a similar position, I bought a cheap after-market Sun Sparc server to run Sparc builds for Ruby for my clients.  It didn't have to be fast.

Comment: This sound promising. This is what I though might be possible (to provide the object files to be linked their-end). Why do you say "it will introduce more problems that it is worth"?

Comment: So you still need a cross compiler to generate the object file for each target architecture.  Or you are still renting machine time to compile all the source files to object code.  You'd have to be ready to hand hold clients that aren't able to link the object files against their libraries using the tool chains they have installed.